# Magento 2.3 localhost Blank page Frontend and admin

Tags: magento2.3, database, localhost, xampp

I'm trying to transfer my test site from web space to local (I'm running low on maximun allowed size)
I've downloaded my database and a copy of the site.
Through Xampp I've imported the database, I've then inserted a copy of the site under the folder /htdocs and proceeded to connect the new database.

This is what i see online
[image]

And this is the same site on localhost
[image]

It's the first time i try to use a site locally, so I don't know what to do.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue in Magento 2 with localhost and solution is below.

File path : vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

Replace full method (function) : isPathInDirectories() and isValid()

```
public function isValid($filename)
{
    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
    if (!isset($this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename])) {
        $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename] =
            ($this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_compiledDir)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->moduleDirs)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_themesDir)
                || $this->_isAllowSymlinks)
            && $this->getRootDirectory()->isFile($this->getRootDirectory()->getRelativePath($filename));
    }
    return $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename];
}


protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath);
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this helps you then hit like and accept as answer.

Thank you
Hiren Patel